# User management backend code to easily copy and implement

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, backend

I'm planning on building an iOS application and want to implement an already built user management(username, first name, last name, phone number, email) instead of me coding it from scratch.

First name
Last name
Username
Phone number
Email

Any recommendations if there is any open source code I could easily copy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS, you could use `AWS Cognito` to perform user management. From the docs

```
Amazon Cognito provides authentication, authorization, and user management for your web and mobile apps. Your users can sign in directly with a user name and password, or through a third party such as Facebook, Amazon, Google or Apple. The two main components of Amazon Cognito are user pools and identity pools.
```

More information here https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/